# Return the maximum value from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, max

I want to return the maximum value and its key from a dictionary, and I know that something like the following should do the trick

```
max(list.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

However in case that the maximum value in a dictionary is 6 and it happens that multiple keys have the same value .. it will always return the first one ! how can I make it return all the keys that has the maximum number as values along with the value. Here is 
an example of a dictionary with the same maximum value:

```
dic={0: 1.4984074067880424, 1: 1.0984074067880423, 2: 1.8984074067880425, 3: 2.2984074067880425, 4: 2.2984074067880425}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The solution using list comprehension:

```
dic={0: 1.4984074067880424, 1: 1.0984074067880423, 2: 1.8984074067880425, 3: 2.2984074067880425, 4: 2.2984074067880425}
max_value = max(dic.values())  # maximum value
max_keys = [k for k, v in dic.items() if v == max_value] # getting all keys containing the `maximum`

print(max_value, max_keys)
```

The output:

```
2.2984074067880425 [3, 4]
```

Comment: What if the two values are exactly the same and you dont have a choice of looking by value?

Comment: That's a tie, any max() algorithm needs to have some sort of tie resolution, maybe lamdba function? @Ahmed

Answer (score 13):

You can first determine the maximum with:

```
maximum = max(dic.values())
```

and then `filter` based on the maximum value:

```
result = filter(lambda x:x[1] == maximum,dic.items())
```

Example in the command line:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> dic={0: 1.4984074067880424, 1: 1.0984074067880423, 2: 1.8984074067880425, 3: 2.2984074067880425, 4: 2.2984074067880425}
>>> maximum=max(dic.values())
>>> maximum
2.2984074067880425
>>> result = filter(lambda x:x[1] == maximum,dic.items())
>>> result
[(3, 2.2984074067880425), (4, 2.2984074067880425)]
```

Given you want to present the **list of keys** are a nice list and the value, you can define a function:

```
def maximum_keys(dic):
    maximum = max(dic.values())
    keys = filter(lambda x:dic[x] == maximum,dic.keys())
    return keys,maximum
```

which returns a tuple containing the list of keys and the maximum value:

```
>>> maximum_keys(dic)
([3, 4], 2.2984074067880425)
```